# Parse push targeted notification

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I'm trying to send a targeted notification via parse but it doesn't work. I use this code to receive

```
ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
// set the current user id
installation.put("device_id", id.getText().toString());
installation.saveInBackground();
```

and this one to send

```
ParseQuery query = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
// id is EditText to write the id of the targeted user manually
query.whereEqualTo("device_id", id.getText().toString());
ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
push.sendMessageInBackground("Hello", query);
```

I've also tried

```
push.setQuery(query);
push.setMessage("Hello");
push.sendInBackground();
```

the manifest has everything that parse said in its quickstart.
Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
    android:name="com.test.singleuserpush.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.test.singleuserpush.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Services and Receivers

```
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

        <category android:name="com.test.singleuserpush" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

None of those worked, any suggestions?

Comment: have u over come from problem?

Comment: @kishorejethava No, didn't find a solution yet

Comment: have you specified all required permission. post manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by enabling client push in App settings, push, enable client push.

Answer (score 0):

try this with `push.setData` instead of `message`

```
JSONObject data;
        data = new JSONObject("{\"userName\": "+
                "\""+"MyUserName"+"\""+
                ",\"profilePic\": "+
                "\""+""+"\"}");

        Log.e("Uber User customdata", data.toString());
        JSONObject obj =new JSONObject();
        obj.put("alert","New Alert Message");
        obj.put("action","com.android.myappname");
        obj.put("customdata",data); //send json

        ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
        push.setQuery(query);
        push.setData(obj);
        push.sendInBackground();
```

Comment: `installation.whereEqualTo("device_id", id.getText().toString());` is not defined